# Need to upload and parse 15MB files, open files twice?

Tags: java, performance, io

I have a file which I need to upload to a service, and parse into relevant data. The parser and the uploader both require an InputStream. Ought I to open the file twice? I could save the file to a String, but having many of these files in memory is concerning.

EDIT: Thought I should make it clear that the parsing and uploading are entirely separate processes.

Comment: If they're separate processes what choice do you have? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Im trying to make a descision about what is the most efficient way to handle something like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate processes".  Is this all in one program or are there two completely different programs involved?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are parsing it already it would be most efficient to load the file into a string. Parse it into indexes to the string, you will save memory and can just upload the string whenever you want to. This would be the most effective way, with memory but maybe not processing time.

A reply to one of the comments above.
Separate processes does not mean different threads or processes, just they do not need each other to operate.